# How to filter out everything except text found in href tag

Tags: html, css, beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup to get site urls, this should save a hyperlink but its getting cluttered with tags

```
carsntrucks = soup2.find(attrs={"data-cat": "cta"})
```

print(carsntrucks) returns

```
<a class="cta" data-cat="cta" href="/d/cars-trucks/search/cta"><span class="txt">cars+trucks<sup class="c"></sup></span></a>
```

print(carsntrucks).a['href'] returns error

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Usually when I do find by class Im able to use a['href'] to filter out, however I cannot here, I think its because i searched by attribute maybe
All I would like to be printed is the href value minus the tag (href="/d/cars-trucks/search/cta") without

Comment: you are already at the `a` tag level so simply take the `['href']` direct off current node `carsntrucks['href']` , also, your `print` statement has the `)` too soon.

Answer (score 0):

print(carsntrucks) returns None. You’re then trying to access an attribute ‘a’ of this None object, which leads to that error message.

I think what you mean to do is carsntrucks.a[‘href’].